Nonfree firmware and codecs packages
I went ahead and installed Ubuntu 24.10 the standard way, one partition. I've been using my computer for a while, so it would be very inconvenient to reinstall.
Besides ubuntu-restricted-extras, are there other packages that get installed when picking those options?
Note: I'm looking to remove them after installation

does this article address your question? Why do you need to remove them after installation? Will they be regarded as illegal in your jurisdiction?

Your question is confusing. What are you try to achieve? Is something not working?

Thanks, the article helped. I just wanted to remove nonfree software from my computer.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
